# What does \* mean in the function signature of PyTorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

For example in the [`randint` signature](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.randint.html#torch.randint) there is a `\*` as 4th argument. What does it mean ?

```py
torch.randint(low=0, high, size, \*, generator=None, out=None, dtype=None, layout=torch.strided, device=None, requires_grad=False) → Tensor
```

I am aware of position only args and keyword only args introduced in Python 3.8 which use `\`  and `*`. But here I see `\*`.

Comment: That looks like someone screwed up some markup or config settings somewhere - it's probably supposed to be a `*`, not `\*`.

Comment: (Also, positional-only arguments use `/`, not `*`, and keyword-only arguments date back to 3.0.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I am aware, thats why I mentioned 'position only args and keyword only args introduced in Python 3.8 which use \ and *.'

Comment: (whoops, meant "not \". Also, again, keyword-only arguments date back all the way to 3.0, not 3.8.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was pretty sure *user2357112 supports Monica* is right. To confirm it, I've tried looking for the source of the documentation, [which is autogenerated](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_sources/generated/torch.randint.rst.txt). I've looked at the implementation, [which is in C++](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/47acdfaa1ee6def741c71579acbb15ad647e6608/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorFactories.cpp#L705) where functions signatures work differently. I found the [type annotation generation code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c7f9da5752baf2280ebeef0a078b9d3e8eb41efc/tools/pyi/gen_pyi.py#L335):

```
        'randint': ['def randint(low: _int, high: _int, size: _size, *,'
                    ' generator: Optional[Generator]=None, {}) -> Tensor: ...'
                    .format(FACTORY_PARAMS),
                    'def randint(high: _int, size: _size, *,'
                    ' generator: Optional[Generator]=None, {}) -> Tensor: ...'
                    .format(FACTORY_PARAMS)],
```

This suggests that the commenter was indeed right, and it should have been `*` rather than `\*`.

Positional arguments in Python are denoted by `/`, not by `\`. In Python's syntax `\` is only used in two places: as an escape character in string literals, and at the end of a line as an explicit line continuation marker.

---

It looks like [this has been an issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/38290) since at least May 2020, with no activity since.